# How to make a Dojox.dgauges indicator appear and disappear

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a circular gauge (subclass of dojox.dgauges.CircularGauge) that has multiple scales, with an indicator (dojox.dgauges.CircularValueIndicator) associated with each scale.

Under certain circumstances, I want the indicator not to show.

```
scale.removeIndicator("indicatorName");
```

correctly causes the indicator to disappear. 
But, later, if I try to add the indicator back, using

```
scale.addIndicator("indicatorName", indicator);
indicator.invalidateRendering();
```

the indicator does not reappear. I can verify using the debugger that the indicator has been added back to the scale, but somehow it is not getting re-rendered.

Any suggestions as to how I should be going about what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the library, I have registered an issue here: https://github.com/ibm-js/dgauges/issues/9

The call to `invalidateRendering` is not needed, it's already triggered by `addIndicator`.

As a temporary workaround, you can write `indicator._indicatorShapeFuncFlag = true;`

You can see the workaround in action at http://jsfiddle.net/dmandrioli/LhWRH/

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: When I try the jsFiddle, and also in my own code, once you remove and then re-add the indicator, it loses its interactivity.

Comment: Add to the workaround: indicator.set("interactionArea", "indicator"); to restore interactivity.